# What does "where I fit" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Fight Club (1999)*, Narrator hugs a very fat man:

> Narrator: He developed bitch tits 'cause his testosterone was too high
> and his body upped the estrogen. That was **where I fit**. Between those
> huge, sweating tits that hung enormous, the way you'd think of God's
> as big.

What does "where I fit" mean?
Does it mean Narrator is also a fat man (or) Narrator fits his body between
those tits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you *watching* the movie?  Presumably you can see if the man is fat or not (he isn't, he is small and thin)

He fits "between those tits" literally, but also metaphorically,  Narrator has found a situation in which he can relax.  A role in which he "fits".

Answer (score 0):

"Where I fit" means that you found the place where you feel good, that's all.

This place fits me = That is where I fit